# C++ Vector Template operator []

Tags: c++, vector, operator-keyword, ostream

Firstly I wanted to say this is a HW assignment and I just have questions in regards to the errors I'm facing

I made a vector template with an insert function that adds a data_type to the end of a dynamic array. This is what I have currently.

```
// Insert the value at the specified index by moving the tail
// when Size = Capacity the Vector has to be reallocated first 
// to accomate the new element
void Insert(const DATA_TYPE& value, int index){

    // If the Capacity is not large enough then ...
    // allocate large vector
    if (Size >= Capacity){
        // 0. Let's boost the capacity
         Capacity += CAPACITY_BOOST;
        // 1. Allocate new larger vector
         DATA_TYPE* newData = new DATA_TYPE[Capacity];

        // 2. Copy from old Data into the newData
         for( int i=0; i< Size; i++)
                newData[i] = Data[i];

        // 3. Delete the old Data
         delete[] Data;

        // 4. Replace old Data-pointer with the newData pointer
        Data = newData;
    }

    // Move the tail
    for(int i=index; i<Size;i++){
        Data[i+1] = Data[i];
    }

    // Insert
    Data[index] = value;
    Size++;

}
DATA_TYPE& operator[] (int index) const{
    return *this[index];
}
```

Note: Using Private Variables: Size, Capacity, Data(stores the dynamic array)
I'm pretty sure I've implemented the add or push_back function correctly. The problem is when ever I try to cout something like "cout << a[1]; " I get an error.

```
while compiling class template member function 'int &Vector<DATA_TYPE>::operator [](int) const'
      with
      [
          DATA_TYPE=int
      ]
see reference to class template instantiation 'Vector<DATA_TYPE>' being compiled
     with
     [
          DATA_TYPE=int
      ]
error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'const Vector<DATA_TYPE>' to 'int &'
    with
     [
        DATA_TYPE=int
      ]
```

Comment: Please stick to 1 question per post.

Comment: Sorry, Thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There should be 2 versions of your `operator[]`:

```
const DATA_TYPE& operator[] (int index) const;
DATA_TYPE& operator[] (int index);
```

What you have is a weird combination of the two.

You should also be returning

```
return Data[index];
```

Returning `(*this)[index];` would result in an infinite recursive call (well, not infinite, you'll get a stackoverflow before that).

Comment: +1  Can you please explain the infinite recursion part ? I think I didn't understand it completely.

Comment: @Mahesh sure - `(*this)[index]` is equivalent to a direct call to `operator[](index)`, which will call itself time and time again.

Comment: Oh shit I'm retarted, I had that before but when I was calling my function to display through cout I tried to show the wrong index (i.e a[1] instead of a[0]) and assumed it had to be changed to *this[index]. I feel dumb -_-. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 2):

There are three problems here:

1. Operator precedence. `*this[index]` is parsed as `*(this[index])`, while you meant `(*this)[index]`.
2. You're returning a mutable reference to your data from a `const` method.
3. The definition of `operator[]` is circular. Returning `(*this)[index]` in `operator[]` would cause infinite recursion.

Comment: Technically there is nothing wrong with returning a mutable reference from that operator (since the reference is to data addressed by a pointer in the object the data itself is not const). Whether or not it is good practice might be debatable and depends on the usecase, but I wouldn't call it a problem

Comment: @Grizzly: I don't think it's what the teacher expects, though.

Comment: I really wouldn't want to speculate on that (in my experience the method signatures are often given in the assignment for such excercises). Which is why I would call that a helpful suggestion rather then a problem less readers interpret it as you can't do that.

Answer (score 1):

The `operator[]` function is declared to be constant, i.e. it can't change anything in the `Vector` object. But it returns a reference, which means that the returned value *can* be modified. These two contradicts each other.

This can be solved by either remove the `const` from the end of the function, or to not return a reference.

Comment: That isn't whats wrong with the OPs code. It might not be a good practice, but it isn't an actual error (when the `operator[]` is correctly implemented at least).